# Json.NET - convert JSON to XML and remove XML version, encoding?

Tags: c#, xml, json, json.net, xml-deserialization

http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/

How come when I use "DeserializeXmlNode" and my JSON gets converted to an XML document
then convert my XML document into a string like this

```
   string strXML = "";
   StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
   xmlDoc.Save(writer);
   strXML = writer.ToString();
```

It includes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
```

I did not add this, how do I remove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use XmlWriter with StringBuilder instead of StringWriter

```
 var strXML = "";
 var writer = new StringBuilder();   
 var settings = new System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings() { OmitXmlDeclaration = true};
 var xmlWriter = System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create(strXML, settings);   
 xmlDoc.Save(xmlWriter);
 strXML = writer.ToString();
```

Answer (score 4):

an XML without that line is not a valid [XML file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML)!

that line is called the **XML Declaration**

as an example, check out the [OData](http://www.odata.org/) XML from **Netflix** on [Catalog Titles](http://developer.netflix.com/docs/oData_Catalog), can you see that first line?

> http://odata.netflix.com/Catalog/Titles

Comment: But I dont need it to be valid, in a web service API. :)

Comment: you should always use that line, or you will not be able to parse it correctly, specially if you now, or in the future use some encoding for special char like `ö` or `ü` etc...